# How to make shift('w','f') return 'b'?

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

Using this program to take out spaces, punctuation, and make letters lower case...

```
def pre_process(s): #Enter: "Jim's secret password."

    s= s.replace("'","")
    s= s.replace('.','')
    s= s.lower()
    s= s.replace(" ","")
    return s
```

How can I encrypt a message so that the letters each shift by an amount equal to the corresponding letter in the alphabet? For example **m** shifted 5 times becomes **r**, but **w** shifted 5 times becomes **b**. This is my current code:

```
def shift(ch,k):    
    return chr(ord('a')+(ord(ch)-ord('a')+k) % 26)
```

Comment: Could you clarify what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Can you post all relevant code, or is this it? If this is all of the code, please clarify what your code is doing and what you're asking.

Comment: I think you gonna get error in `(ord(ch)-ord('a')+k)` since you try add string into int return value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def shift(ch, k):
    return chr(ord('a') + ((ord(ch) - ord('a')) + 
                           (ord(k) - ord('a'))) % 26)
```

Sort of an explanation:

```
def shift(ch, k):
    #
    # k_delta
    # ────>
    #
    # ch_delta                 k_delta
    # ────────────────────────>────>
    # a....f.........m....r....w..zab
    # ──────────────>────>         ┊
    # ch_delta       k_delta       ┊
    #                              ┊
    #                             %26

    ch_delta = ord(ch) - ord('a')
    k_delta = ord(k) - ord('a')
    return chr(ord('a') + (ch_delta + k_delta) % 26)
```

Unless `k` varies, you can use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to speed up encryption:

```
import string
message = 'mw'
key = 'f'
enc_table = string.maketrans(
    string.ascii_lowercase,
    ''.join(shift(c, key) for c in string.ascii_lowercase)
)
message.translate(enc_table) # -> 'rb'
```

I'd also suggest replacing the [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants) `26` with `len(string.ascii_lowercase)` for example.

Decryption can be done using the same function, but with a different key. The relation between them is that `enc_delta + dec_delta = 0 modulo 26`. From this results that `dec_delta = -enc_delta % 26`. Therefore:

```
dec_k = chr(ord('a') + ((ord(enc_k) - ord('a'))) % 26)
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I then decrypt that so ('b','f') returns 'w'?

Answer (score 0):

You changed question.

Following to according to old question: How to make shift('w','f') return 'b'?

1. Get difference of second argument from the alpha `a`, code is `diff = a2-start`
2. Get next value from the first argument by adding difference, code is `next = a1+diff`
3. Check next value is greater then alpha `z` or not.
4. If not greater then `z` then new value is next value.
5. If greater then get new value from alpha `a`
6. Return value character.

code:

```
def shift(ch,k):
    start = ord("a")
    end = ord("z")
    a1 = ord(ch)
    a2 = ord(k)

    diff = a2-start
    print "\ndiff:", diff
    next = a1+diff
    print "next value:", next
    if next>end:
        new = next-end-1
        print "new1:", new
        new = start + new  
    else:
        new = next

    print "new value:", new

    return chr(new)


rs = shift("w", "f")
print "w and f:", rs

rs = shift("e", "b")
print "e and b:", rs

rs = shift("z", "b")
print "z and b:", rs

rs = shift("x", "b")
print "x and b:", rs
```

output:

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 26.py 

diff: 5
next value: 124
new1: 1
new value: 98
w and f: b

diff: 1
next value: 102
new value: 102
e and b: f

diff: 1
next value: 123
new1: 0
new value: 97
z and b: a

diff: 1
next value: 121
new value: 121
x and b: y
vivek@vivek:~/D
```

Answer (score 0):

Decrytion/Encryption Python

code:

```
def shift(ch, k):
    return chr(ord('a') + ((ord(ch) - ord('a')) + (ord(k) - ord('a'))) % 26)


def reshift(ch, k):
    tmp =  (ord(ch) - (ord(k) - ord('a')))
    if tmp<ord('a'):
        tmp = ord("a") +(26 - (ord("a") - tmp))
    return chr(tmp)

print "w and f:"
re = shift("w", "f")
print "Encryption:", re
re = reshift(re, "f")
print "Decrytion:", re

print "----------"
print "e and b"
re = shift("e", "b")
print "Encryption:", re
re = reshift(re, "b")
print "Decrytion:", re

print "----------"
print "z and b"
re = shift("z", "b")
print "Encryption:", re
re = reshift(re, "b")
print "Decrytion:", re

print "----------"
print "x and b"
re = shift("x", "b")
print "Encryption:", re
re = reshift(re, "b")
print "Decrytion:", re
```

output:

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 26.py 
w and f:
Encryption: b
Decrytion: w
----------
e and b
Encryption: f
Decrytion: e
----------
z and b
Encryption: a
Decrytion: z
----------
x and b
Encryption: y
Decrytion: x
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$
```