# Encryption Python - encrypting a string

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

Using this program to take out spaces, punctuation, and make letters lower case...

```
def pre_process(s):
    s= s.replace("'","")
    s= s.replace('.','')
    s= s.lower()
    s= s.replace(" ","")
    return s
```

How can I encrypt a message (s) so that the letters each shift by an amount equal to the corresponding letter in the alphabet? ex) 'm' shifted 5 becomes 'r' but 'w' shifted 5 becomes 'b'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make shift('w','f') return 'b'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756582/how-to-make-shiftw-f-return-b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be helpful to you...Just change the value of shifter in encrypt function to get the corresponding shift

```
def shift(char,shift_by):
    val=ord(char) #gives ascii value of charecter
    val+=shift_by
    if(val>122):
        val=97+(val-122-1)
    return(chr(val))

def encrypt_string(str):
    shifter=2 #change to value of shifter here
    encrypted_string=""
    for i in str :
        if( (ord(i)>=97) and (ord(i)<=122) ):
            i=shift(i,shifter)
        encrypted_string+=i
    return(encrypted_string)
```

Comment: `if(...)`, `return(...)` works, but it's ugly by Python's standards i.e. [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). `(ord(i)>=97) and (ord(i)<=122)` can be replaced with `97 <= ord(i) <=122`.

Comment: Yes,you are totally correct...I guess it will take a while to drop my C coding style :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do some `ord` and `chr` tricks to do what you want. Basically, these two functions return the integer representation of your letters, and outputs the corresponding letter of the integer representation, respectively.

```
def pre_process(s):
    s= s.replace("'","")
    s= s.replace('.','')
    s= s.lower()
    s= s.replace(" ","")

    mystring = ""
    for letter in s:
        shift = 5
        r = ord(letter)+shift
        if (r > ord('z')):
            r -= 26
        mystring += (chr(r))
    return mystring
```

Comment: Damn beat me to it !!  Very quick, was typing almost the same thing